# Do until the row is blank

Tags: excel, vba, loops, outlook

I'm trying to assign Outlook tasks to my team members using VBA.

```vb
Sub tasksV1()

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutTask As Outlook.TaskItem
Dim i As Integer
Do Until (Cells(i, 1) = "")
i = 2
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Set myRecipient = OutTask.Recipients.Add(Cells(i, "H"))
myRecipient.Resolve
If myRecipient.Resolved Then
With OutTask
Do Until (Cells(i, 1) = "")
.Subject = Cells(i, "C")
.StartDate = Cells(i, "E")
.DueDate = Cells(i, "E") + 2
.ReminderTime = .DueDate - 1
.Body = "Please mark the task as completed once the document is updated with the document       mentioned in subject."
.Assign
.Display
 i = i + 1
 Loop
End With
End If
Set OutTask = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I would like to repeat the code until the row is blank.

The code runs once and stops.

Comment: Why is `i = 2` at the start of your while loop? Try setting it above the first `Do Until` and delete the second one. Also get your `End With` and `End If` in the loop. Not sure if the logic to increase the i was needed in a separate loop but you'd be better off working with multiple variables then or at least fix the loops.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile at all: You are opening two loops but closes only one. Indent your code properly to see such problems.

Comment: Empty cells can be a burden in Excel. I believe you better check if the length of the value of the cell equals zero.

Comment: This may help in future  ...  https://www.automateexcel.com/vba-code-indenter/

Comment: While `.Value` is default property and therefore will give you correct results but it is not considered as a good practice.

Comment: Thank you all for your guidance ,I was able to fix the code with these suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub tasksV1()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2 ' --- should be here
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") ' --- should be here
    Do Until (Cells(i, 1) = "")
        ' i = 2 --- wrong place
        ' Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") --- wrong place
        Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
        Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient ' --- not the best place, move it up to sub header
        Set myRecipient = OutTask.Recipients.Add(Cells(i, "H"))
        myRecipient.Resolve
        If myRecipient.Resolved Then
            With OutTask
                ' Do Until (Cells(i, 1) = "") --- error here, extra line
                .Subject = Cells(i, "C")
                .StartDate = Cells(i, "E")
                .DueDate = Cells(i, "E") + 2
                .ReminderTime = .DueDate - 1
                .Body = "Please mark the task as completed once the document is updated with the document       mentioned in subject."
                .Assign
                .Display
                 ' i = i + 1 --- wrong place
            End With
        End If
        i = i + 1 ' --- should be here
    Loop
    Set OutTask = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Extra 'Do' prevents the code to be compiled. Every time you've edited the code you need to Compile them from Debug menu for error checking.

I didn't check your script overall, especially task/recipient relationship.

Comment: Sounds good, you can mark my answer as accepted/helpful.